# Java: An abstract class contains a static field of self class initialized strangely

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt

In the Eclipse CDT plugin, I found this unusual way of initializing a field of an abstract class.

The field ALL refers is a class of the class itself.

```
abstract public class IndexFilter {
    public static final IndexFilter ALL = new IndexFilter() {};
    ....
}
```

What is the role of new IndexFilter() {}; ?

Can you explain this initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexFilter() {};` creates an "anonymous subclass" of `IndexFilter`. Since the braces are empty, the subclass does not override anything in the base class. Since IndexFilter is abstract, it cannot be instantiated directly, hence why a subclass is required.

Comment: It's similar to inline instantiation of an interface.

Comment: quote : "Since IndexFilter is abstract, it cannot be instantiated directly, hence why a subclass is required."  The class needs a static final IndexFilter field. A static final field needs to be initialized when declared. And the only way to initialize it is to use a subclass of IndexFilter because IndexFilter is an abstract class. Using an anonymous subclass is an elegant way to achieve this. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you refer to as "unusual" is the fact that it's an anonymous inner (or to be more precise, nested) class.

`new IndexFilter() {}` creates a concrete subclass of `IndexFilter` and an instance of that subclass in one expression. Obviously this is only possible because `IndexFilter` hasn't got any abstract methods. If it had, you'd have to provide an implementation for them between the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the filter will pass all information. Normally, filter meant to filter some entries. ALL is the special case here. You can also think of NONE as special case which will filter out all information.

Example:

```
a.select(b, IndexFilter.ALL);
a.select(b, new IndexFilter() {
   ...
});
```

Other class that uses such pattern is Integer which has MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's meant to just be a single easily-accessible instance of `IndexFilter` which doesn't override anything.